# Does collisions of ideal gas molecules effect its equation of state?

Tags: collision, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, molecular-dynamics

I have been reading Statistical Mechanics by R. K. Pathria & Paul D. Beale , 4th edition . In this book they used a quantity called Virial , which is defined as $\mathcal{V} = \langle\Sigma q_iF_i\rangle$ where $F_i$ denotes the force acting on ith particle and $q_i$ is its position , to derive the equation of state for the ideal gas . 
In this derivation , only the force due to the reaction force of the container wall is taken into account and the collision force between two molecules is ignored on the assumption that the dimension of the molecules are so small that any two molecules are very much less likely to collide with each other than to collide with the container wall . 
 But it is also an assumption in kinetic theory that the ideal gas molecules collide elastically with one another . If this mutual collisional force is also taken into account , shouldn't the equation of state of an ideal gas change ? 
 I'm sure that I'm misinterpreting something but don't exactly know what , so I'd like if anyone shares their thought on the matter . Thank you in advance .

Comment: All those elastic collisions of ideal gas atoms with other atoms only serve to keep the ideal gas in thermal equilibrium. There is no net energy being transferred to anything else.

Comment: I believe one of the assumptions for ideal gas behavior is collisions between molecules and between molecules and the container walls are perfectly elastic.

Comment: @JonCuster But why aren't the force due to the collision is not taken into account. I understand that the collision between the molecule is very rare . So is the actual ideal gas composed of particles that do not collide ? Because the equation of state is based on that assumption.

Comment: @BobD I also believed this assumption but for some reason collision of molecules if is taken into account in the virial the equation of state certainly change . Maybe it's nothing but ambiguity in the definition of ideal gas , but I still want to be sure .

Comment: @blackphoton Check out https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Thermodynamics_and_Chemical_Equilibrium_(Ellgen)/02%3A_Gas_Laws/2.13%3A_Virial_Equations

Comment: @blackphoton - the forces between molecules act only on the assemblage of molecules. They may redistribute energy from one molecule to another, and that is important to keep the molecules in equilibrium with each other. The net effect on the gas is nothing.

Comment: @JonCuster I think i got it now . The equation of state pv = nRT is an approximate description of the gas composed of particles that collide with each other . I believe this ought to be the case as there is of course no gas that has molecules that do not ever collide .  And that's why for rarefied gas this approximation holds .